# Creating Onion Omega Cross-Compiling environment on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, openwrt

Trying to setup development environment on Ubuntu 20.10 according official manual:

https://docs.onion.io/omega2-docs/cross-compiling.html

Got error below while running make command:

```
/usr/include/asm-generic/int-ll64.h:31:42: error: conflicting types for '__u64'
   31 | __extension__ typedef unsigned long long __u64;
      |                                          ^~~~~
In file included from <command-line>:
././include/compiler.h:69:18: note: previous declaration of '__u64' was here
   69 | typedef uint64_t __u64;
      |                  ^~~~~
```

Why I'm getting this? I did all steps in right way. How to fix that?

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure why this issue has come up however, you can reference:

[OpenWRT Compile Error](https://forum.openwrt.org/t/compile-error-19-07/44423)

[OpenWRT Build Error](https://forum.openwrt.org/t/solved-build-error-make-toplevel-mk-world-error-2/47478/28)

The solution is to modify the a file in your buid_dir

```
build_dir/host/u-boot-2018.03/include/compiler.h
```

Remove/Comment out line 69 which contains:

```
typedef uint64_t __u64;
```